# How can integer and double values be the same in Java?

Tags: java

```
class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int i=1;
     double d=1.0;
     if(i==d)
        System.out.println("True") // whether any type casting happens.
     else 
        System.out.println("false");
   }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html  see 5.1.2, widening conversions

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relevant quote from the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) :

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>   
> ...
>   2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> **- If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double**.

In your case `i` is converted to `double` in order to perform the comparison.